# Calculate delta between measurements while preserving the same units across rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
MEASUREMENT <- c("Length","Width","Breadth","Height") 
MULTIPLIER <-  c(1,0.1,1000,1)
df1 <- data.frame(MEASUREMENT,MULTIPLIER)

INPUT_MEASUREMENT <- c("Length","Length","Breadth","Breadth","Height")
INPUT_AVERAGE <- c(4.3,4.2,0.001,0.003,7)
INPUT_TARGET <- c(4,4,0.005,0.005,10)
OUTPUT_MEASUREMENT <- c("Breadth","Breadth","Length","Width","Height")
OUTPUT_AVERAGE <- c(0.006,0.011,6.8,68,9)
OUTPUT_TARGET <- c(0.005,0.005,6,60,10)
df2 <- data.frame(INPUT_MEASUREMENT,INPUT_AVERAGE,INPUT_TARGET,
                  OUTPUT_MEASUREMENT,OUTPUT_AVERAGE,OUTPUT_TARGET)
```

I am trying to create 2 columns `DELTA_AVERAGE`, `DELTA_TARGET` in df2 which are the absolute value of (output - input) averages and targets respectively. Since each measurement is in a different scale, I would like to use the multiplier column in df1 for the respective measurements before calculating the delta average and target so that the resulting dataframe has same units across all the rows.

My desired output is

```
  INPUT_MEASUREMENT INPUT_AVERAGE INPUT_TARGET OUTPUT_MEASUREMENT OUTPUT_AVERAGE OUTPUT_TARGET DELTA_AVERAGE
             Length         4.300        4.000            Breadth          0.006         0.005           1.7
             Length         4.200        4.000            Breadth          0.011         0.005           6.8
            Breadth         0.001        0.005             Length          6.800         6.000           5.8
            Breadth         0.003        0.005              Width         68.000        60.000           3.8
             Height         7.000       10.000             Height          9.000        10.000           2.0
  DELTA_TARGET
             1
             1
             1
             1
             0
```

I am trying to do it this way but not getting it right

```
input.df <- unique(merge(df1, df2[c("INPUT_MEASUREMENT")], 
                             by.x="MEASUREMENT", by.y="INPUT_MEASUREMENT"))
output.df <- unique(merge(df1, df2[c("OUTPUT_MEASUREMENT")], 
                              by.x="MEASUREMENT", by.y="OUTPUT_MEASUREMENT"))
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df2 %>%  
  mutate(DELTA_AVERAGE = abs((OUTPUT_AVERAGE * output.df$MULTIPLIER) - 
                               (INPUT_AVERAGE * input.df$MULTIPLIER)),
         DELTA_TARGET = abs((OUTPUT_TARGET * output.df$MULTIPLIER) - 
                            (INPUT_TARGET* input.df$MULTIPLIER)))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" here is to make 2 copies of your `df1` and rename the columns:

```
# create data
df1 <- data.frame(
    measurement = c("Length","Width","Breadth","Height"),
    multiplier  = c(1,0.1,1000,1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    input_measurement = c("Length","Length","Breadth","Breadth","Height"),
    input_average = c(4.3,4.2,0.001,0.003,7),
    input_target = c(4,4,0.005,0.005,10),
    output_measurement = c("Breadth","Breadth","Length","Width","Height"),
    output_average = c(0.006,0.011,6.8,68,9),
    output_target = c(0.005,0.005,6,6,10),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# copy and rename df1 so can be merged as both input and output
df1_input <- df1
names(df1_input) <- c("input_measurement", "input_multiplier")

df1_output <- df1
names(df1_output) <- c("output_measurement", "output_multiplier")

# merge df1 onto df2 twice (once for input, once for output)
df2 <- merge(df2, df1_input,  by="input_measurement")
df2 <- merge(df2, df1_output, by="output_measurement")

# calculate deltas
df2$delta_average <- df2$output_average * df2$output_multiplier - df2$input_average * df2$input_multiplier
df2$delta_target  <- df2$output_target  * df2$output_multiplier - df2$input_target  * df2$input_multiplier
```